# Issue with parser xml

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I've this xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>Le joyeux médecin</title>
            <description>
                <p>test blague description</p>
            </description>

            <pubDate>Dimanche, 02/03/2014</pubDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
```

And the code to parse the xml :

```
        private void Feed(object Sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            XElement _xml;
            try
            {
                if (!e.Cancelled)
                {
                    _xml = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
                    Results.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("channel").Elements("item"))
                    {
                        _item = new Flux();
                        _item.Title = value.Element("title").Value;
                        _item.Description = Regex.Replace(value.Element("description").Value,
                        @"<(.|\n)*?>", String.Empty);
                        Results.Items.Add(_item);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }
        }
```

`_xml` contains the xml but the code into the `foreach` doesn't execute and I don't know why... thanks for any help !

Comment: Is this your exact XML? It does not appear to contain a root element, which may cause problems. If you can control the XML, I suggest you add a root element wrapping the `<channel>` elements, e.g. `<channels> ... </channels>`.

Comment: @SolalPirelli `<channel>` appears to be the root element...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your loop as:

```
foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("item"))
{

}
```

Since `_xml` is already `channel`